# jquery 1.5 ajax requests are erroring

Tags: php, json, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-1.5

trying to upgrade to jQuery 1.5 and all my ajax calls break. I'm running firefox and it gives me a javescript error of invalid Label 
I'm using php's json_encode 
here is my json response

```
{
    "page": "1",
    "total": 9651,
    "rows": [
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51438",
                "Skin color: Handy tool for teaching evolution",
                "2011-02-20 08:30:26"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51435",
                "Photosynthesis may hold key to production of cheap hydrogen for fuel",
                "2011-02-19 10:00:03"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51478",
                "Dancers, supporters ready for THON 2011 Feb. 18-20 at Jordan Center",
                "2011-02-18 14:26:25"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51420",
                "Juggling languages can build better brains",
                "2011-02-18 13:30:44"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51434",
                "Multiple approaches necessary to tackle world's food problems",
                "2011-02-18 13:30:44"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51436",
                "U.S. will no longer dominate science and research, study finds",
                "2011-02-18 13:00:49"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51492",
                "NPR to air interview with Penn State professor today (Feb. 18)",
                "2011-02-18 11:20:10"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51437",
                "Research universities play a major role in national security",
                "2011-02-18 10:30:28"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51472",
                "Paterno's necktie from 400th win nets $10,200 for Public Broadcasting",
                "2011-02-18 09:20:52"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51363",
                "PSU Extension offers free tax preparation help for low-income families",
                "2011-02-18 01:32:04"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51477",
                "Students set to produce complete THON coverage, including webcast",
                "2011-02-17 15:24:47"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51385",
                "The Medical Minute: Seasonal Affective Disorder",
                "2011-02-17 12:27:30"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51345",
                "Abington professor's new book exposes NBA betting scandal",
                "2011-02-17 11:59:31"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51360",
                "Student Stories: Statistical service internship makes it all add up",
                "2011-02-17 11:12:32"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51453",
                "Parking Office announces parking, transit changes related to THON",
                "2011-02-17 11:02:46"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51444",
                "Penn State's Lunar Lion team aims to land vehicle on moon by 2015",
                "2011-02-17 08:17:12"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51427",
                "Students flock to Spring Career Fair",
                "2011-02-16 12:56:27"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51419",
                "Ice Campaign receives $1 million gift from Paul and Nancy Silvis",
                "2011-02-16 10:51:45"
            ]
        },
        {
            "cell": [
                "story",
                "51353",
                "CarbonEARTH program facilitates science education, teaching",
                "2011-02-15 15:59:04"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "messages": null
}
```

all this works fine in jquery 1.4.2

think I'll have to wait to upgrade but thought I would check and see if anyone else had a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I found the correct solution after some searching I found a [bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8064) for the jQuery Validate. At the bottom of the report the author of validate provides a forked version which fixes the problem thanks to all for help

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug and it is fixed in 1.5.1. See ticket http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8125, You can find the latest jQuery release with up to date fixes at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js

You can also try `jQuery.ajaxSetup({ jsonp: null, jsonpCallback: null});` as per this thread [JQuery 1.5 and new "Text JSON" datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955582/jquery-1-5-and-new-text-json-datatype/5006475#5006475)

Comment: -git version does nothing to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it happens due to a bug in jquery.validate.js. There is a quick (not recommended!) fix `jQuery.ajaxSetup({ jsonp: null, jsonpCallback: null});` - if it works for you, look further into different options, [there is a discussion](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8084) of "Invalid Label" problem in version 1.5.

Comment: so far, if I take out jQuery.validate.js the problem gos away as well the fix you gave me fixes the problem I'm gonna look at the discussion  you linked to now.

Comment: could you tell me what the disadvantage of using your fix is ?

Comment: @mcgrailm - If you ever need to use jsonp for mash-ups etc., this will get in the way.
More about JSONP: [http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/]